# using reduce to sum values in array of objects gives error

Tags: javascript

I want to sum up the thinking like the following code:

```js
const bests = [
 {
   thinking: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0c', sum: 64, num: 1 },
    listening: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0d', sum: 129, num: 2 },
    speaking: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0e', sum: 0, num: 2 },
    writing: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0f', sum: 0, num: 0 },
    speed: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc10', sum: 187, num: 2 },
    overall: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc11', sum: 129, num: 2 }
  },
 {
     thinking: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a6', sum: 100, num: 1 },
    listening: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a7', sum: 100, num: 1 },
     speaking: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a8', sum: 100, num: 1 },
     writing: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a9', sum: 0, num: 0 },
     speed: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4aa', sum: 88, num: 1 },
     overall: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4ab', sum: 100, num: 1 }
   },
   {
     thinking: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4af', sum: 10, num: 10 },
    listening: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b0', sum: 65, num: 1 },
     speaking: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b1', sum: 0, num: 1 },
    writing: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b2', sum: 0, num: 0 },
    speed: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b3', sum: 95, num: 1 },
    overall: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b4', sum: 65, num: 1 }
  }
 ]
 
 
 

const sum = bests.reduce((a, b) => a['thinking'].sum + b['thinking'].sum);
console.log('sum::', sum);
```

But as you see I get the wired error!
How can I fix this?

Comment: `a` is the accumulator, it doesn't have a `thinking` property, you should use something like `a + b.thinking.sum` but in order for this to work, you need to set a starting value for the accumulator. You can do that like this: `bests.reduce((a, b) => a + b.thinking.sum, 0);`

Comment: `const sum = bests.map(a => a.thinking.sum).reduce((a, b) => a + b);` ?

Comment: Also related, if not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66825357/215552 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/33392307/215552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code give you the expected results.

```js
const bests = [
 {
   thinking: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0c', sum: 64, num: 1 },
    listening: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0d', sum: 129, num: 2 },
    speaking: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0e', sum: 0, num: 2 },
    writing: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0f', sum: 0, num: 0 },
    speed: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc10', sum: 187, num: 2 },
    overall: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc11', sum: 129, num: 2 }
  },
 {
     thinking: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a6', sum: 100, num: 1 },
    listening: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a7', sum: 100, num: 1 },
     speaking: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a8', sum: 100, num: 1 },
     writing: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a9', sum: 0, num: 0 },
     speed: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4aa', sum: 88, num: 1 },
     overall: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4ab', sum: 100, num: 1 }
   },
   {
     thinking: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4af', sum: 10, num: 10 },
    listening: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b0', sum: 65, num: 1 },
     speaking: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b1', sum: 0, num: 1 },
    writing: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b2', sum: 0, num: 0 },
    speed: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b3', sum: 95, num: 1 },
    overall: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b4', sum: 65, num: 1 }
  }
 ]
 
 // changed code block start

const sum = bests.reduce((a, b) => a + b['thinking'].sum,0);

 // changed code block end

console.log('sum::', sum);
```

Explanation : `a` is the sum of all values before adding current value. Therefore it is a number not an item of this list and calling `a['thinking'].sum` cause error because `a` is a number therefore `a['thinking']` is undefined. `b` is the current item of list. Also you have to pass the initial value which is 0.

Comment: Please add some details to your answer. "change the code as above" does not help OP. Explain what you did, and why!

Answer (score 2):

The first param of [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is the accumulator, no need for `['thinking]` on that:

Pass `0` as the initial value, so the accumulator becomes an integer, THen we can just add the `b['thinking'].sum`:

```
bests.reduce((a, b) => a + b['thinking'].sum, 0);
```

```js
const bests = [{thinking: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0c', sum: 64, num: 1 }, listening: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0d', sum: 129, num: 2 }, speaking: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0e', sum: 0, num: 2 }, writing: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc0f', sum: 0, num: 0 }, speed: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc10', sum: 187, num: 2 }, overall: { _id: '6347d5b4edc3227f056cbc11', sum: 129, num: 2 } }, {thinking: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a6', sum: 100, num: 1 }, listening: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a7', sum: 100, num: 1 }, speaking: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a8', sum: 100, num: 1 }, writing: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4a9', sum: 0, num: 0 }, speed: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4aa', sum: 88, num: 1 }, overall: { _id: '6347e46665609042876fc4ab', sum: 100, num: 1 } }, {thinking: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4af', sum: 10, num: 10 }, listening: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b0', sum: 65, num: 1 }, speaking: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b1', sum: 0, num: 1 }, writing: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b2', sum: 0, num: 0 }, speed: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b3', sum: 95, num: 1 }, overall: { _id: '6347e54f65609042876fc4b4', sum: 65, num: 1 } } ];

const sum = bests.reduce((a, b) => a + b['thinking'].sum, 0);
console.log('sum::', sum);
```